# How to write dynamic code for pivoting a table in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I wrote below code to pivot the below given sample table in db2.

**Sample_Table**

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |

**Expected Output**

| Column_A | Column_B_1 | Column_B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 2 |

**Code:**

> select Column_A ,
> max(case when Column_B = '1' then Column_B end) as Column_B_1 ,
> max(case when Column_B = '2' then Column_B end) as Column_B_2
> from Sample_Table
> group by Column_A ;

As you can see that number of columns ie. `Column_B_1, Column_B_2` are hardcode. How can I dynamically determine the number columns? This will help me to handle a table which has more or less duplication of data in `Column_A` than what I have hardcode.

I tried to dynamically generate the SQL using repetitive concatenation within while loop. And then execute that SQL code. But that did not work.